# What should be the ratio between training time and accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, performance

What should be the ratio between time and accuracy?
I mean when should you drop the accuracy a little bit but it will take less time for the Classifier/Regressor to run?

Edit: As part of my studies I have to build a classifier for the Fashion-Mnist data set without using neural networks, I am using XGBoost as the classifier, and I see that with one set of hyperparameters I get 0.898 accuracy score, and with another set, I get 0.904.
The difference is that the first second classifier takes more than double the time to train.
My question is when should you take the classifier that takes less time to train but drops the accuracy as well?

Comment: By time, can you clarify if you mean time to train Vs time to run an inference? Also it helps to understand the size of the dataset for either situation. Also some context on the model and how it will be consumed by users wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Why do you specify accuracy to 3 sf? Is is actually so precise? I think it would help to get some sense of the confidence interval here. Can you run cross-validation? My guess is that your confidence interval is probably few percent wide so the difference between 0.898 and 0.904 is meaningless. Once  you have run cross-validation, you should be able to see which of the two classifiers is consistently better, and if they are both the same, I would go with the faster one :-)